# Respond to touch event for both child and parent

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ontouchlistener, event-bubbling

I have a child view layered on a parent view. Both have `touchUpInside` listeners attached. When the user pressed the child, I want both the child and the parent view to respond to this touch event. When the user only presses the parent, I want only the parent listener to fire.

How do I do this?

I've tried overriding the following method in my child view, but returning false here completely ignores the event on the child. Conversely, if I handle the touch event in the child, it is ignored for the parent.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have subclasses for both views, you can override the [UIView touchesBegan](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) method. If you call the super `touchesBegan` method, then this should produce the result you're after as the event travels up the responder chain. (i.e. if the user taps the child view, the touch event for both the child and parent will respond)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    print("TOUCHED")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick Example...

Tap the "innerView" and you'll see two "touches began" debug prints. Tap the "outerView" and you'll see only one.

```
class TouchView: UIView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("touches began in \(self)")
    }

}

class TouchTestViewController: UIViewController {

    let innerView: TouchView = {
        let v = TouchView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let outerView: TouchView = {
        let v = TouchView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(outerView)
        outerView.addSubview(innerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            outerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            outerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            outerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            outerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

            innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            innerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            innerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.centerXAnchor),
            innerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerView.centerYAnchor),

            ])

    }

}
```